# How to modify screen width/height proportion with key combinations

Tags: windows-7

Win7 comes with a nice feature that you can reposition and align the current window with key combos such as :

- <kbd>win</kbd> + (<kbd>up</kbd> | <kbd>down</kbd> | <kbd>left</kbd> | <kbd>right</kbd>)

By default if the window gets positioned to the left edge of the screen, it has 50% of the screen width. Is if there's a way to customized this proportion, say to 70% or whatever.